# ‘the first and the third book’ or 'the first and the third books'?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

'book' or 'books'?

I suspect that it should be 'book', because the full sentence should be 'the first book and the third book'.

Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll be **books** in this case.

While that's decent reasoning, it's not quite right. The full sentence would be

> the first book and the third book

Two separate books and you're considering both of them in

> the first and the third book**s**

....so, you use the plural.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you would generally use the *plural*

> The first and the third books **are**...
>   The first and third books **are**...